# Working with CSS 3 and Multiple Images

Tags: html, css

I am working with a template that has a header .css and a div in the html calling that class 'header_panel'.

It works as written, calling 'header_panel' but if I try to change the header in any way to 'header_panel_a' to place a different background image on the html page, calling the class from the css, nothing is displayed.

```css
/*========================================================
                     HEADER  Section
=========================================================*/
header {
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
}
header .brand {
  float: left;
}
header .nav {
  float: right;
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  header {
    text-align: center;
  }
  header .brand, header .nav {
    float: none;
  }
}

.header_panel {
  height: 350px;
  background: url(../images/bluepeople.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.header_panel_a {
  height: 350px;
  background: url(../images/fence.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.header_panel_b {
  height: 350px;
  background: url(../images/sign1.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!--========================================================
                              HEADER
    =========================================================-->
    <header class="header_panel">
    
    </header>
```

Comment: are you using: <header class="header_panel_a"> and do you see anything in console?

Comment: Hey Michele, another solution could be this... Perhaps there is some code somewhere else in the website files that are interfering. 

So, what I would do is simply keep the "header_panel" div that the template has in the html and CSS, and then just change the image source, instead of creating a whole new header.

That way, if you want the header to show different backgrounds in the future, all you have to do is change the image source and that's it.